# Looping a functions based on elements of a list

Tags: r, function, datatable, sapply

I am having some trouble trying to loop a function based on a list and creating a table of results.

```
head(Dat17_18.3[,c(1,3:5)])
                     Program Area I.E.ScoreStat I.I.ScoreStat I.P.ScoreStat
1             BFA - Art Education             2             2             2
2 BA - Foreign Language Education             2             2             3
3      MAT - Elementary Education             2             2             2
4            BA - Dance Education             2             3             3
5      MAT - Elementary Education             2             3             3
6      MAT - Elementary Education             2             2             3
```

I have used the `split` function to create a list of program areas.

```
test1<- split(Dat17_18.3, Dat17_18.3$`Program Area`)
```

I wrote a function to extract elements from a from the `alpha` function in the `psych` package.

```
alpha_fun <- function (df,columns){
  library(psych)
  a1 <- alpha(df[,columns])
  a2 <- alpha.ci(a1[[1]][1],nrow(df),length(columns))
  vec1 <- c(nrow(x),a1[[1]][1],a2[1],a2[3],a1[[1]][3])
  return(vec1)
}
```

I want to have the `alpha_fun` run for each element in the Test one to create a table for all of the program areas at once.

Comment: What are the parameters to your function? Which one is the data frame and what is the other and where does it derive? It is advised to use more clear names: `function(df, num)`?

Comment: the parameters of the function are x=df, y=col_numbers.

Comment: Do you have package restrictions? Would you be open to solutions using, e.g., ` dplyr`, `data.table`, or `purrr`? Or do you want to stay mostly in base R?

Comment: @Gregor, No restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `by` (object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`) which is akin to `split` + `lapply` where a function can be directly applied to each subset of data frame grouping. Also, avoid the need for the *columns* parameter which can be retrieved from data frame input inside the method:

```
library(psych)

alpha_fun <- function (df){   
  sub <- df[, 3:ncol(df)]              # KEEP ONLY NUMERIC COLS

  a1 <- alpha(sub)
  a2 <- alpha.ci(a1[[1]][1], nrow(sub), ncol(sub))
  vec1 <- c(nrow(sub), a1[[1]][1], a2[1], a2[3], a1[[1]][3])

  return(vec1)
}

# LIST OF VECTORS 
alpha_vec_list <- by(Dat17_18.3, Dat17_18.3$`Program Area`, alpha_fun)

# MATRIX WITH Program Area AS ROW NAMES
alpha_mat <- do.call(rbind, alpha_vec_list)
```

Comment: the ```alpha_vec_list``` is running ```alpha_fun``` across the whole dataset including the two character columns, which ```alpha_fun``` not handle.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your issue. Can you rephrase? The `by` function should be sending *Program_Area* subsets of your whole dataset (not whole df) into the *alpha_fun* method. What exactly is the output of *alpha_vec_list*?

Comment: The ```alpha_fun``` only accepts numeric values so when the ```Dat17_18.3``` which includes characters the ```alpha_fun``` won't run. I have tried to specify which columns to use in the ```by``` (i.e., ```by(Dat17_18.3[,3:12], Dat17_18.3$`Program Area`, alpha_fun)``` statement which will make the ```Dat17_18.3$`Program Area` ``` unused.

Comment: See update where you can subset the columns inside your *alpha_fun* before calling `alpha`. Note the other lines reference now to *sub* (not *df* input).